# How to check whether a file is open already in COBOL?

Tags: file, cobol, indexed

I am trying to find out a way to check whether a file is already opened in COBOL, so that I can open it if it is closed or close it if it is opened.

Thnx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the `FILE STATUS` and act accordingly.

Try the following:

Add a `FILE-STATUS` under the `FILE-CONTROL`, for example:

`FILE-CONTROL.
        SELECT  MYFILE ASSIGN MYDD
                ORGANIZATION SEQUENTIAL
                ACCESS       SEQUENTIAL
                FILE STATUS  MYFILE-STATUS.`

Declare a `FILE STATUS` variable in `WORKING-STORAGE`
as a `PIC X(2)` value, for example:

`01 MYFILE-STATUS   PIC X(2).
              88 MYFILE-ALREADY-OPEN   VALUE '41'.`

Then in the `PROCEDURE DIVISION`issue an `OPEN` for your
file. Immediately following that, test the value of `FILE STATUS`
as in:

`OPEN MYFILE....
    IF MYFILE-ALRADY-OPEN
       CLOSE MYFILE...
    END-IF
    IF MYFILE-STATUS <> '00'
       perform some sort of general error routine
    END-IF`

Values of `FILE STATUS` where the first character is not a '9', are
COBOL standard values so testing for '41' to detect an already open file
should work on all COBOL implementations. Beware when the first character is a '9',
these are vendor specific file status codes. Check out the following link for
a good introduction to using COBOL `FILE STATUS`: http://www.simotime.com/vsmfsk01.htm

Comment: Thnx a lot, especially for the link. I am totally new to Cobol, so the resource is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler may also provide a external API, such as CBL_CHECK_FILE_EXIST which can be found on Micro Focus COBOL, AcuCOBOL and Fujutsu COBOL.

For example, on Micro Focus COBOL:

```
 copy "cblproto.cpy".

 program-id. MYMAIN.
 working-storage section.
 01  .
     05  file-details    cblt-fileexist-buf.

 procedure division.
     call 'CBL_CHECK_FILE_EXIST' using 'mymain.cbl '
                                       file-details
     if  return-code not = 0
       display "File mymain.cbl does not exist (or error)"
     else
       display "File mymain.cbl size is " cblt-fe-filesize
       of file-details
     end-if
 end program MYMAIN.
```